# google analytics is not tracking my events

Tags: google-analytics, event-tracking

I use google analytics code:

```
var gaJsHost = (("https:" == document.location.protocol) ? "https://ssl." : "http://www.");
document.write(unescape("%3Cscript src='" + gaJsHost + "google-analytics.com/ga.js'     type='text/javascript'%3E%3C/script%3E"));


var pageTracker = _gat._getTracker("UA-26272684-1");
pageTracker._initData();

pageTracker._trackPageview();
```

and then

```
<a class = "download_link" href="http://www.hugeone.co.uk/catal/a-boards.pdf" target="_blank" onclick="_gaq.push(['_trackEvent','Download','PDF',this.href]);">Download a-boards.pdf </a>
```

but nothing is actually tracked

I'm not an analytics specialist.

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You are mixing up two versions of the Analytics code. The initialization code should look like this:

```
var _gaq = _gaq || [];
_gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'UA-*******-1']);
_gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);

(function() {
var ga = document.createElement('script'); ga.type = 'text/javascript'; ga.async = true;
ga.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://ssl' : 'http://www') + '.google-analytics.com/ga.js';
var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(ga, s);
})();
```

With this, you can access the `_gaq` variable that you are accessing in your download tracking code. Then everything should work fine (untested).

As a sidenode, you can use the [Google Analytics Debugger extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/google-analytics-debugger/jnkmfdileelhofjcijamephohjechhna?hl=en) to debug those errors.